# web上ではうまく文字抽出できるのに，pythonで正規表現がうまくいかない

Tags: python, 正規表現

以下の正規表現を用いて文章から文字列を抽出したいです．

```
[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*
```

この正規表現が正しいかをweb上で確認したところ以下の図のように文字を抽出できました．

- 例
  [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これを用いてPythonでも同様のことを行うとしたのですがうまくいきませんでいた．

```
test_data = '検索したい文字列'
result = re.findall(r'/*[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*', test_data)
```

おそらくPythonコードの書き方に何か問題があるのだと思います．
どこに問題があるのか教えていただきたいです．
よろしくお願いします．

Comment: このヘルプ記事[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考に、他の人が問題を再現・調査出来るような最小限のソースコードおよびテストデータをテキストで提示してみてください。あと使用しているOS,環境,IDE,Pythonの種別・版数等、そして上手くいきませんでしたという状況の詳細を過不足無く追記してください。例えばテストデータはこちらの記事[Conflicting with version dependencies when running pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66450085/9014308)に類似しているようですが。あとこんなサイトもあります。[regex101](https://regex101.com/), [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/), [Regular Expression Test Page for Python](https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html)

Comment: 念のため、動作確認に使ったwebサイトのURLも質問中に含めてみてください。一口に正規表現と言っても言語ごとに対応が微妙に異なるので、どのような環境で試したのか詳しい情報があった方がより的確なアドバイスが付きやすくなると思います。

Answer (score 0):

うーん、抜き出したいのは、

- 1文字以上で
- 1文字目は英数字か - で
- 2文字目以降は英数字と - に加えて . もあり

なのではないですか？
それなら`r'[\w-][\w\.-]*'`で良いかと。

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript の正規表現エンジンと同様の結果を得るには non-capturing match group を使います。

[Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

> `(?:...)`
>
> A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or referenced later in the pattern.

```py
import re

test_data = '''
['Conflicting with version dependencies when running pip install',
"Hi everyone, Having issues with version dependencies when running `pip install` on docker.
However, when installing on my mac without docker and just virtualenv, works perfectly fine.
**Mac OS** - macOS Mojave v10.14. **Python Version** - v3.7.3 **Docker Compose Version** -
version 1.27.4, build 40524192 Here's the first error I got when running the docker-compose
up I tried to loosen the `six` package from `six==1.10.0` to `six>=1.2,<=1.15.0` And throws
a different error for requests package this time. Here's the error
'''

result = re.findall(r'[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*', test_data)
print(result)

## 結果(適宜改行を入れています)
['Conflicting', 'with', 'version', 'dependencies', 'when', 'running', 'pip',
 'install', 'Hi', 'everyone', 'Having', 'issues', 'with', 'version', 'dependencies',
 'when', 'running', 'pip', 'install', 'on', 'docker', 'However', 'when', 'installing',
 'on', 'my', 'mac', 'without', 'docker', 'and', 'just', 'virtualenv', 'works',
 'perfectly', 'fine', 'Mac', 'OS', '-', 'macOS', 'Mojave', 'v10.14', 'Python',
 'Version', '-', 'v3.7.3', 'Docker', 'Compose', 'Version', '-', 'version', '1.27.4',
 'build', '40524192', 'Here', 's', 'the', 'first', 'error', 'I', 'got', 'when',
 'running', 'the', 'docker-compose', 'up', 'I', 'tried', 'to', 'loosen', 'the',
 'six', 'package', 'from', 'six', '1.10.0', 'to', 'six', '1.2', '1.15.0', 'And',
 'throws', 'a', 'different', 'error', 'for', 'requests', 'package', 'this', 'time',
 'Here', 's', 'the', 'error']
```

その他に [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.finditer) を使う方法があります。

```py
result = [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*', test_data)]
```